# Boost::geometry::buffer not working with geographic coordinates system

Tags: c++, boost, geometry

I am using boost 1.69.0 with VisualStudio 2015. What I want to do, is create a buffer around a geometry that uses geographic coordinate system:

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>

int main()
{
//    using point_type = boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>;
    using point_type = boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::geographic<boost::geometry::degree>>;
    using polygon_type = boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_type>;

    std::vector<point_type> v1{{0,0}, {0,10}, {10,10}, {10,0}, {0,0}};
    polygon_type poly1;
    boost::geometry::assign_points(poly1, v1);

    boost::geometry::correct(poly1);

    const double buffer_distance = 1;
    const int points_per_circle = 18;

    boost::geometry::strategy::buffer::distance_symmetric<double> distance_strategy(buffer_distance);
    boost::geometry::strategy::buffer::join_round join_strategy(points_per_circle);
    boost::geometry::strategy::buffer::end_round end_strategy(points_per_circle);
    boost::geometry::strategy::buffer::point_circle circle_strategy(points_per_circle);
    boost::geometry::strategy::buffer::side_straight side_strategy;

    boost::geometry::model::multi_polygon<polygon_type> poly2;

    boost::geometry::buffer(poly1, poly2, distance_strategy, side_strategy, join_strategy, end_strategy,
            circle_strategy);

    return 0;
}
```

This example code works fine with cartesian coordinate system. When I use geographic (or spherical_equatorial) I get this kind of compilation error:

> include\boost/geometry/strategies/cartesian/side_of_intersection.hpp(58): **error C2338: boost::is_integral::value**
>   include\boost/geometry/strategies/cartesian/side_of_intersection.hpp(158): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::geometry::strategy::side::detail::multiplicable_integral' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               T=coordinate_type
>           ]
>   include\boost/geometry/strategies/cartesian/side_of_intersection.hpp(212): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'int boost::geometry::strategy::side::side_of_intersection::sign_of_compare(const T &,const T &,const T &,const T &)' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               T=coordinate_type
>           ]
>   include\boost/geometry/strategies/cartesian/side_of_intersection.hpp(321): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'int boost::geometry::strategy::side::side_of_intersection::sign_of_addition_of_two_products(const T &,const T &,const T &,const T &)' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               T=coordinate_type
>           ]

I can understand the compiler reaches unimplemented method for double, but the question is why it works for double with cartesian and does not work for double with geographic coordinate system?
Does anyone know a way to workaround this problem?

Comment: Polygon in Geographic CS is just not supported as input to `buffer` function, what you can see on [reference site](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/buffer/buffer_7_with_strategies.html). `buffer` can accept only `point` for GCS.

Comment: Still the question is if I can workaround this problem in any reasonable way?

Comment: @dioda Do map projection to cartesian plane, calculate cartesian buffer, project back to ellipsoid.